# Why I cannot find the inverse matrix of A with the second method?

Tags: matrices, inverse

[Assume A = [(1,0,-2),(-1,3,2),(5,0,-1)]is a matrix, then find the inverse of A.
I have tried to find the inverse of A this way:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9L5ki.png)
[image]
[However, I don't understand what's wrong in the following solution instead.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0mK4.png)
[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: 3 is an eigenvalue of$A$.

Comment: Please don't use pictures for text or formulas.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34121/why-image-cannot-be-used-for-explaining-my-maths-problem), why. Use MathJax - here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

The second approach fails when you "cancel" $A-3I$, because it's quite possible that $A-3I$ doesn't have an inverse.

One way to check this sort of thing in general is to take the answer you got at the end and substitute it in for "A" in each previous line, and see where you start to not get equality any more; *that's* where your mistake is.